# Specify Source directory for Docker Builder Image

Tags: docker

**Note:** *I had problems finding a good title. If you have a better idea for the title feel free to edit the title.*

In the past I have used the following builder image to containerize the build process of a Spring Boot app.

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn clean package
```

I don't like this container design, because the resulting container image is useless if the source code changes, because if the source code or pom.xml changes I need to rebuild the docker image. Instead I want a builder image which takes a `src` directory and a `pom.xml` and executes `mvn clean package` when running the container.

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
COPY pom.xml ./
COPY src ./src
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "clean", "package"]
```

I now use `mvn clean package` as the entrypoint. This way `mvn clean package` gets execute every time the container starts and not just on `docker build`. But the problem remains. The `src` directory and `pom.xml` is copied during the docker build process.

**So here is my question:** Is there a way to specify the `src` directory and `pom.xml` when executing `docker run` ? Can I achieve this by mounting a volume?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `specifying`?  First, you built the image and second you want to run it? Could tell us what u want to achieve? If the code is changed you have to build again.

Comment: There are no options to build and run at the same time. Rather you can use `ADD` instead to copy the source once.

Comment: Aren't you overcomplicated things? There's an example in the [Maven image docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) that lets you specify a source folder using the official image: `$ docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/mymaven -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.3-jdk-8 mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mvn"]
```

This solution works. Run it with:
`docker container run --name build -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp myapp:build mvn clean install`
However, for this you can just use the maven image as @timsmelik has suggested in the comments.